# Access 2010: How to open an Oracle linked table field in new window

Tags: oracle, ms-access, editor

I have some Oracle tables linked in Access 2010. Is there a way to open a field value in a new window (or dialog)? Something like when you double-click on a long string field in Toad (the value is opened in a window, in order to edit it with comfort).

Note: I want to do it in a linked table, not in a form nor a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift+F2 works in most objects (forms, tables etc) to open a zoomed window for a field / column.

See also [Keyboard shortcuts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-access-HP010341802.aspx)

Comment: Great, thank you! I see that, once the new window is opened, all the text is selected, and if I press the right arrow key (or left or up or down), then the buttons on the right are select . But I've just discovered that I can press F2 to edit the text directly. So, to edit a field quickly in a new window: Just press shift+F2 and then F2.